# Resizing Android recycler items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In a contraint layout for a recyclerview I use an invisible imageview as a sizer-object, that I constrain other views to. The idea is that by resizing the imageview I will resize the entire recyclerview item.

The XML for the imageview is:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSizer"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Then, in my onBindViewHolder, I try to resize by using the ScaleX and ScaleY property of the sizer view:

```
holder.itemView.ivSizer.scaleX = scale
holder.itemView.ivSizer.scaleY = scale
```

This produces a run-time error (the scale variable is of type Float):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set 'scaleX' to Float.NaN
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. Am I going about this the wrong way? The reason I want to do the resize is that I can change the number of columns in a grid layout manager, and want to zoom the items to follow suit.

Comment: What is `scale` at this point?

Comment: What was the value of scale variable?

Comment: ```val scale: Float = width.toFloat() / columns.toFloat() / holder.itemView.ivSizer.width.toFloat()```, where width is the width of the recyclerview (about 1000), columns is the number of columns in the recyclerview (from 1 to 5) and the width of the Sizer is 100, so in effect scale is a float with a value between 2 and 10, more or less...

Answer (score 1):

Oops... I discovered that the width of the recyclerview is 0 - so scale is 0.

Which explains the error; I can't set ScaleX and ScalY to 0 :-p

Now, why `recyclerWidth = rvFolderList.width`would return 0, even after I have set the layout manager and adapter is a conondrum (to me) - but that's another matter :-)

Thanks for answering me!